# PyTorch - How to specify an input layer? Is it included by default?

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, stable-baselines

I am working on a Reinforcement Learning problem in StableBaselines3, but I don't think that really matters for this question. SB3 is based on PyTorch.

I have 101 input features, and even though I designed a neural architecture with the first layer having only 64 nodes, the network still works. Below is a screenshot of my model architecture:
[image]

I am concerned because I thought that the first layer of the neural network needed to have a number of nodes equal to the number of input features.

Does PyTorch include an input layer by default, and doesn't display it? If so, how can I know and control what the activation functions etc. are for the input layer?

EDIT:
Here are my imports and basic code, in response to Michael's comment.

```
import gym
from gym import Env
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from gym import spaces
from gym.utils import seeding
from stable_baselines3.common.vec_env import DummyVecEnv, SubprocVecEnv
from stable_baselines3.common.utils import set_random_seed
from stable_baselines3.common.evaluation import evaluate_policy
from stable_baselines3.common.env_util import make_vec_env
from stable_baselines3 import PPO
import math
import random
import torch as th

from sb3_contrib.common.maskable.policies import MaskableActorCriticPolicy
from sb3_contrib.common.wrappers import ActionMasker
from sb3_contrib.ppo_mask import MaskablePPO
from sb3_contrib.common.envs import InvalidActionEnvDiscrete
from sb3_contrib.common.maskable.evaluation import evaluate_policy
from sb3_contrib.common.maskable.utils import get_action_masks

env = MyCustomEnv(....)
env = ActionMasker(env, mask_fn)  # Wrap to enable masking

# Defining custom neural network architecture
mynetwork = dict(activation_fn=th.nn.LeakyReLU,
                     net_arch=[dict(pi=[64, 64], vf=[64, 64])])

# Maskable PPO behaves just like regular PPO
model = MaskablePPO(MaskableActorCriticPolicy, env, verbose=1, learning_rate=0.0005, gamma=0.975, seed=10, batch_size=256, clip_range=0.2,
                    tensorboard_log="./log1/", policy_kwargs=mynetwork)
# To get the screenshot I gave
print(model.policy)
```

Comment: Please include the entire model, imports and example input as text not as images. A `torch.nn.Linear` layer wouldn't run with a different sized input tensor. The input would be a tensor not *nodes* (is this a GNN?). `pytorch` doesn't add an 'adapter' layer by default.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny Thank you for your feedback, I added my model, and imports. Are you saying it would be helpful for me to include a text of one row of my data? To be totally clear, what I don't understand is why there's no error/problem associated with my number of input features being totally different from the number of nodes in the first layer I specified (as I thought those two needed to be the same. 20 inputs = 20 nodes in first layer).

Comment: I'm not familiar with `sb3`, I recommend tagging with more specific tags if they are available to draw attention to field experts.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny So you're saying you believe this phenomenon is specific to SB3, not to PyTorch?

Answer (score 1):

We can do a little bit of digging inside Stable Baselines' source code.

Looking inside the [`MaskableActorCriticPolicy`](https://github.com/Stable-Baselines-Team/stable-baselines3-contrib/blob/master/sb3_contrib/common/maskable/policies.py#L21), we can see it [builds a MLP extractor](https://github.com/Stable-Baselines-Team/stable-baselines3-contrib/blob/master/sb3_contrib/common/maskable/policies.py#L137-L150) by initializing an instance of [`MlpExtractor`](https://github.com/DLR-RM/stable-baselines3/blob/master/stable_baselines3/common/torch_layers.py#L136) and creating the `policy_net` sub-network [here](https://github.com/DLR-RM/stable-baselines3/blob/master/stable_baselines3/common/torch_layers.py#L221) whose layers are defined in [this loop](https://github.com/DLR-RM/stable-baselines3/blob/master/stable_baselines3/common/torch_layers.py#L201-L212). Ultimately the layers feature sizes are dictated by the `"pi"` and `"vf"` *list*s in side of `net_arch` ([see here](https://github.com/DLR-RM/stable-baselines3/blob/master/stable_baselines3/common/torch_layers.py#L188)).

If you trace back this you will notice those parameters can be modified as the `net_arch` argument on `MaskableActorCriticPolicy` [header](https://github.com/Stable-Baselines-Team/stable-baselines3-contrib/blob/master/sb3_contrib/common/maskable/policies.py#L48).

Comment: Hi Ivan, I appreciate your links and references to the source code. I will dig around in there, but unfortunately, I still don't see the input layer. Correct me if I'm wrong - the input layer needs to be the same number of nodes as your number of inputs. If this is correct, then my input layer needs to be 101 nodes/units. However, I defined my first layer (through net_arch argument) as having 64 units, and there was no error. So.. is PyTorch automatically making an input layer of the correct size before feeding it to the layers I explicitly defined? Do you see my dilemma?

Comment: No PyTorch will never introduce additional layers ;). So this is definitely a behaviour of Stable Baselines itself. Can you provide the code where you changed the input size?

Comment: Huh, good to know. Well, you can actually see it in the code I already posted. The line where I defined "mynetwork = ...." is where I defined that I wanted my vf network and pi network to have 64 units in first layer and 64 units in second layer.